# Bootable USB Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb

I see that this has been asked around here before.  But not only are the answers over a year out of date, they all point to a Windows installer that is known to have a virus.

I know this for a fact now because I just downloaded it.  It passed two scans and failed on the third.  So, it indeed is virus infected.  That would be the one from peninstaller.com.

I think that's pretty messed up that everyone is still pushing that thing when even their OWN site says it's known to be infected.  How stupid is that?!

Anyway...  I have the Ubuntu ISO.  But I have it on a machine with no CD burner.  I really need to use it to make a USB drive bootable.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If past answers have become incorrect/now point to viruses, please identify them specifically so a moderator can update them accordingly. Is there anything wrong with the official Ubuntu guides? Look [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for creating a USB from Windows, [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) for Mac, and [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) for Ubuntu.

Comment: I'll post a comment back here.  I have to go look that back up again.  But it was actually DIRECTLY on the Ubuntu site.  The same place I downloaded the ISO.

Comment: ok, here is the site:  http://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-ubuntu-10-04-on-flash-drive-using-windows/
That was linked up directly from:  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
It's the very first link on the page.

Comment: So fair warning to anyone doing the same thing as me.  Follow the answer provided by przemo below.  That one is correct.  In fact, it worked so well, I'm posting THIS from the new Ubuntu installation!

Comment: Yes.  I purposely attached it to a GMail so I could have them scan it.  That's the one that identified it.  I'd consider them to be pretty reliable.

Comment: Confirmed using Gmail and ClamAV on Ubuntu. Flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: A virustotal scan comes out clean: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/0ff7dff701c555bd02afe168302a9e77bccad951d6f82093d2d66409af15d05c/analysis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu you can use usb-creator-gtk.

On Windows you can use http://www.linuxliveusb.com/.

Comment: That would be great if I were running Ubuntu.  Which I'm clearly not, or I wouldn't be trying to install it from Windows.  In the meantime, I have a liveboot Knoppix.  I'll try that one...  I'll still check back here though, as Ubuntu is my first choice.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ ? I have used it myself.

Comment: no.  but I will now.  I'll check back and let you know how it goes.

Comment: So far so good.  It doesn't appear to have a virus.  :)

Comment: So far you appear to be the winner.  The installer seems to have worked fine.  Now I just need to try booting up off it.  Wish me luck!

Comment: yep.  it worked!  Excellent!  Thank you, sir.  Never underestimate Stack Overflow sites...